# How to remove redirect error page which is not even indexed from Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console

however I don't remember for requesting indexing for that subsite, Google Search Console says redirect error for the URL `https://example.com/subsite` where the real URL should be the same but ending with `/`. (So `https://example.com/subsite/`.)

This second one (so the right one) is indexed, everything is fine (and also have a canonical tag). But Search Console gave me a warning for the first one that it has redirect error. (Redirecting to the second one.)

How can I remove that first URL from Search Console? Because that URL is not even indexed. But the warning and red vertical lines for that URL is there, which is annoying, since I don't use that URL, not present on my site, not even in the sitemap.xml.

So I just want to remove it. But the only option I see is to fix and re-scan it. I don't want to do that, I don't need that URL, I don't have that URL.

All the option I can think about is maybe add it to `robots.txt`. But I don't like that solution, to add something there what should not exist on the first place.

Comment: When checking GSC results, sometimes you'll find things you didn't submit. There's a selector on the upper left side to filter results for only the URLs you have submitted. That will reduce all the false positives and allow you to focus in whatever needs correcting.

Answer (score 1):

If the page is set to render with the trailing slash and the sitemap is correct, the other URL is likely getting indexed from an internal link that does not have the trailing slash. Crawl your site and see if you can find it. Search Console might show you where it was discovered also.